# How to continue running the Code after an Exception occurs?

Tags: java, xml, spring, exception, xml-parsing

I am parsing a xml file and it has some errors in it. I want to parse the file through java and print all the parse exceptions in a separate text file.But, the code stops to run after it encounters the first parse exception. Any way to do this so that the code runs even after experiencing an exception while parsing. I  want all the errors not a single one.

```
private final Document getDocument(String filepath)
        throws ParseException, TransformerException, SAXException, ParserConfigurationException, IOException {

    DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = docBuilder.parse(filepath);
    return doc;
}
public void printErrorsInXmlForParse() {
    String filepath = "//anypath";
    try {
        getDocument(filepath);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the code that's not working?

Comment: use try catch block?

Comment: using try catch block only prints the first error while parsing , I want all the other errors as well  after the first exception. I am parsing a xml file in java.

Comment: add a code snippet from what you have done

Comment: Can you put that code inside the question

Comment: e.printStacktrace only tells me about the first error in the xml parsing. I want all of them.

Comment: I don't believe that's possible. As soon as an exception is thrown, your code will stop parsing the xml.